# Task Scheduler Script copy NEW files only - Synology

Tags: linux, synology

Similar to this [question](https://community.synology.com/enu/forum/1/post/126455) I want to make a task scheduler script to copy NEW files (last 24h) to a new folder.
I try to use this code:

```
find /volume1/start/ -mtime -1  -type f -exec cp -r {} /volume1/target/ \;
```

but it delivers a 1kb filename.pdf@SynoEAStream file instead of the file itself.

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Ok actually it seems to work as supposed I actually just had the wrong file modification date in the files where it didn't work. The script additionally copies some "useless" @SynoEAStream files whicht I now avoid by only looking for pdf-files which ist what I wanted.

```
find /volume1/TestScan/start/ -mtime -1  -type f -iname '*.pdf' -exec rsync -r {} /volume1/TestScan/ziel/ \;
```

Maybe its helpful for someone